# Reportlab myFirstPage override MyLaterPage

Tags: templates, reportlab

I'm beginner with reportlab and I've a strange issue when I build my pdf. MyFirstPage template overwrites myLaterPages.

```
def myFirstPage(canv, doc):
  canv.saveState()  
  canv.line(left_margin, top_margin, right_margin, top_margin)
  canv.setFont('Times-Italic',12)
  canv.drawString(right_margin - 100, top_margin + 10, "Report")
  canv.drawImage('logo.jpg', left_margin, top_margin, width = 90, height= 30)
  canv.setFont("Times-Bold", 36)
  canv.drawCentredString(0.5 * A4[0], 7 * inch, "Rapport journalier d activite")
  canv.line(left_margin, top_margin, right_margin, top_margin)
  canv.line(left_margin, bottom_margin, right_margin, bottom_margin)
  canv.drawCentredString(0.5*A4[0], 0.5 * inch,"Page %d" % canv.getPageNumber())
  canv.restoreState()


def myLaterPages(canv, doc):
  canv.saveState()  
  canv.line(left_margin, top_margin, right_margin, top_margin)
  canv.setFont('Times-Italic',12)
  canv.drawString(right_margin - 100, top_margin + 10, "Report")
  canv.drawImage('logo.jpg', left_margin, top_margin, width = 90, height= 30)
  canv.line(left_margin, top_margin, right_margin, top_margin)
  canv.line(left_margin, bottom_margin, right_margin, bottom_margin)
  canv.drawCentredString(0.5*A4[0], 0.5 * inch,"Page %d" % canv.getPageNumber())
  canv.restoreState()

def create_pdf_report(pdfname = 'report.pdf'):
  code = [200, 404]
  app = ['webserver01, webserver02']
  doc =   SimpleDocTemplate(pdfname,rightMargin=5,leftMargin=5,topMargin=0,bottomMargin=5)   
  result = []
  for a in app:
    result.append(Spacer(1, 70))
    result.append(create_table_website_ref(a))
    result.append(create_pi_graphic(a))
    result.append(Spacer(1, 30))
    for i in code:
        result.extend(create_table_graph_row(a, i))
        result.append(Spacer(1, 30))
    result.append(PageBreak())
doc.build(result, onFirstPage=myFirstPage , onLaterPages=myLaterPages)
```

Thanks

Comment: how do you mean the one overwrites the other? can you explain in some more detail what is happening ano what you think should happen.

Comment: Sure, my generated pdf hasn't my first page(only her) but all other have the myfirstpage like template. mylaterpages is never used.

Answer (score 0):

After

`doc = SimpleDocTemplate(pdfname,rightMargin=5,leftMargin=5,topMargin=0,bottomMargin=5)`
you have to add `frame` and `template` section with `doc`
e.g.

```
frame = Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width, doc.height, id='normal')
    template = PageTemplate(frames=frame, onPage=header)
    doc.addPageTemplates([template])
```

This will add your first page while rendering pdf. Now, to add later pages template insert
`result.append(NextPageTemplate('header'))`
before rendering content of second page.